# Jmeter batch - Only 1 script runs while running multiple scripts in batch

Tags: jmeter

Hi I want to run multile jmx files creating a batch file I tried with the below mentioned ways ,but unable to make it run multiple scripts.

cd C:\jmeter-2.6\apache-jmeter-2.6\bin

jmeter -n -t C:\jmeterlatestshoppingscripts\Cache_Availability.jmx -l "c:\jtl\prk1.jtl"

cd C:\jmeter-2.6\apache-jmeter-2.6\bin

jmeter -n -t C:\jmeterlatestshoppingscripts\correct_finance_data.jmx -l "c:\jtl\prk2.jtl"

as above after runing 1 script i am again setting jmeter path .BUT still it is running only the first script and stopping and creating 1 jtl for first ascript.Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a single file with one thread group for each scenario, and set the testplan to run concurrently. See [How to run JMeter in non giu mode](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)